# javascript regex replace 1st and 3rd space in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 2 types of strings. One of them has only 1 space and the second one has 3 spaces.

- V1: `"100 s"` => 1 space. Number followed by a letter. Number can be 1..n digits.
- V2: `"2 W 10 h"` => 3 spaces. Each number is followed by a letter. Again numbers can be 2..n digits.

I need to get rid of the spaces following the numbers. So the end results should be this:

- V1: `"100 s"` -> `"100s"`
- V2: `"2 W 10 h"` -> `"2W 10h"`

For now, I use JavaScript split function. However I need regex to replace in a more efficient way. Could you help me with that? Thanks.

```
const getDelayValue = delayString => {
    const splitted = delayString.split(/\s+/);
    if (splitted) {
        if (splitted.length === 2) {
            return `${splitted[0]}${splitted[1]}`;
        }
        return `${splitted[0]}${splitted[1]} ${splitted[2]}${splitted[3]}`;
    }
    return delayString;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to remove the spaces

```js
const str1 = '100   s';
const str2 = '2 W 10 h';

function removeSpace(str) {
  // as @ Keith pointed out, you can also use :
  // return str.replace(/(\d+) +/g, '$1');
  // \d is a shortcut for [0-9]

  return str.replace(/([0-9]+) +/g, '$1');
}

console.log(removeSpace(str1));
console.log(removeSpace(str2));
```

---

We are matching a number followed by a space. And then replace it by the number only. To create and test your Regexp, you can use the website https://regex101.com/

[image]

[image]

Comment: I came to the same idea, but just used `\d` instead of `[0-9]`  Oh, and did ` +` to handle multiple spaces between.

Comment: @Keith Great comment. I've edited my answer applying your recommendations to it.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `numbers space string` with `numbers string`:

```js
str = `
100 s
2 W 10 h
`

console.log(
  str.replace(/(\d+)\s+([a-z]+)/gi, "$1$2")
)
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) for the meaning of `$1` in the replacement.